# how to horizontally center-crop div inside other div

Tags: css, crop, centering

Trying to horizontally center and crop (if necessary) a div inside of another div.

It's possible to achieve this same effect with a background image, but in this case my content is not a single image.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7aMhY/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="poster_container">
  <div class="poster_row">
    <div class="poster" style="width: 210px;">1</div>
    <div class="poster" style="width: 210px;">2</div>
    <div class="poster" style="width: 210px;">3</div>
    <div class="poster" style="width: 210px;">4</div>
    <div class="poster" style="width: 210px;">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.poster_container {
  text-align: center;
  border: dotted;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: #0ff;
  margin: auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.poster_row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  oveterflow:hidden;
  border: dotted;
  border-color: blue;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.poster {
  border: dotted;
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: green;
  background-color: green;
  height: 315px;
  font-size:280px;
  color: white;
}
```

As long as the poster_container div is wider than the poster_row div, the content is centered. But once poster_row is wider, it crops but its content is flush left and cropped on the right only.

I'm trying to have the inner poster_row div center and crop equally from both sides. The outer div will be 100% of the viewport, so its width is arbitrary. Ideally I'd like the inner div to have arbitrary width as well, so I can easily swap out content without changing the CSS.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with pure css, with js you can say margin-left -50% on the poster row and then plus half of poster's row width which will center the poster row horizontally. But I cannot think of anything off the top of my head to achieve this with only css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it :

I let you add your prefixes and remove the max-width value

```
.poster_row {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: dotted;
    border-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Comment: This nukes the height of the `.poster_container`, but otherwise solves the problem. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7aMhY/4/

Comment: This works. The other solution using margin-left and width works fine too with one caveat which I've noted as well.

Answer (score 1):

if the width of your poster_row isn't about to change add:

```
.poster_row {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: dotted;
    border-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -525px;
    width: 1050px;
}
```

otherwise you have to calculate the width and margin-left with Js

Comment: As the OP stated "Ideally I'd like the inner div to have arbitrary width as well, so I can easily swap out content without changing the CSS."

Comment: Yes ideally the width is arbitrary, but this solution works fine. One caveat: I had to set overflow-x:hidden in the div containing poster_container to prevent a horizontal scroll bar.