# Centering an image within a div, both axes

Tags: css

I am trying to make a picture fit in a `div` box. However, I need to align it so the *center* om the picture is in fact in the center of the `div`. The dimensions of the picture varies.

In the example below, I first need to adjust the width to fit the picture using `max-width: 100%`. However, now the Y axis is not centered (the bottom of the picture is cut off instead of half bottom half top).

How can I center that like in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: wow...Such an attractive question... :)

Comment: can you give some code or maybe a jsFiddle...

Comment: i fall in love with this question XD

Comment: Why would you want to crop this pretty lady? :)

Comment: Check the following answered question maybe it helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473954/how-to-horizontally-center-crop-div-inside-other-div

Comment: @ Patrick : hard luck man.. try to change the image to get answers .. :D

Comment: Do you have any support condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy to have the picture be a `background-image` rather than an actual `img` element, the following should work:

```
 #imagediv { 
   background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go :

```
.container {
    background-image : url('http://khongthe.com/wallpapers/people/cute-face-218642.jpg'); /* put your image here */
    width: 420px; /* as you want */
    height: 420px; /* as you want */
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-size : cover;*/ /*bonus*/
}
```

and use this html :

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/46CJy/).

This is a classic problem. I am pretty sure you could find it on Google by the way. Have fun with my snippet.